# Why is `sklearn.manifold.MDS` random when `skbio's pcoa` is not?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-algebra, multi-dimensional-scaling, skbio

I'm trying to figure out how to implement `Principal Coordinate Analysis` with various distance metrics.  I stumbled across both `skbio` and `sklearn` with implementations.  **I don't understand why `sklearn`'s implementation is different everytime while `skbio` is the same?** Is there a degree of randomness to `Multidimensional Scaling` and in particular `Principal Coordinate Analysis`? I see that all of the clusters are very similar but why are they different? Am I implementing this correctly?

Running `Principal Coordinate Analysis` using `Scikit-bio` (i.e. `Skbio`) always gives the same results:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn import decomposition
import seaborn as sns; sns.set_style("whitegrid", {'axes.grid' : False})
import skbio
from scipy.spatial import distance

%matplotlib inline
np.random.seed(0)

# Iris dataset
DF_data = pd.DataFrame(load_iris().data, 
                       index = ["iris_%d" % i for i in range(load_iris().data.shape[0])],
                       columns = load_iris().feature_names)
n,m = DF_data.shape
# print(n,m)
# 150 4

Se_targets = pd.Series(load_iris().target, 
                       index = ["iris_%d" % i for i in range(load_iris().data.shape[0])], 
                       name = "Species")

# Scaling mean = 0, var = 1
DF_standard = pd.DataFrame(StandardScaler().fit_transform(DF_data), 
                           index = DF_data.index,
                           columns = DF_data.columns)

# Distance Matrix
Ar_dist = distance.squareform(distance.pdist(DF_data, metric="braycurtis")) # (n x n) distance measure
DM_dist = skbio.stats.distance.DistanceMatrix(Ar_dist, ids=DF_standard.index)
PCoA = skbio.stats.ordination.pcoa(DM_dist)
```

[image]

Now with `sklearn`'s `Multidimensional Scaling`:

```
from sklearn.manifold import MDS
fig, ax=plt.subplots(ncols=5, figsize=(12,3))
for rs in range(5):
    M = MDS(n_components=2, metric=True, random_state=rs, dissimilarity='precomputed')
    A = M.fit(Ar_dist).embedding_
    ax[rs].scatter(A[:,0],A[:,1], c=[{0:"b", 1:"g", 2:"r"}[t] for t in Se_targets])
```

[image]

Comment: The MDS terminology is quite confusing, see [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/14017) to find a good description of the differences.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

scikit-bio's PCoA (`skbio.stats.ordination.pcoa`) and scikit-learn's MDS (`sklearn.manifold.MDS`) use entirely different algorithms to transform the data. scikit-bio directly solves a symmetric eigenvalue problem and scikit-learn uses an iterative minimization procedure [1].

scikit-bio's PCoA is deterministic, though it is possible to receive different (arbitrary) rotations of the transformed coordinates depending on the system it is executed on [2]. scikit-learn's MDS is stochastic by default unless a fixed `random_state` is used. `random_state` appears to be used to initialize the iterative minimization procedure (the scikit-learn docs say that `random_state` is used to "initialize the centers" [3] though I don't know exactly what that means). Each `random_state` may produce slightly different embeddings with arbitrary rotation [4].

References: [[1]](https://github.com/biocore/scikit-bio/issues/579#issuecomment-51549066), [[2]](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/qiime-forum/oAgFnRCzSsA/27P2PqLqnpkJ), [[3]](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.MDS.html), [[4]](http://baoilleach.blogspot.com/2014/01/convert-distance-matrix-to-2d.html)

Answer (score 1):

MDS is a probabalistic algorithm, there is a parameter `random_state` that you can use to fix the random seed, you can pass this if you want to get the same results each time. PCA on the other hand is a deterministic algorithm, if you use `sklearn.decomposition.PCA`, you should get the same results each time.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer.  Whenever I look up `PCoA` (Principal Coordinate Analysis not Principal Component Analysis), the links send me to `MDS`.  Why is it that one implementation is not based on a `random_state`?